# Symfony 3 Form builder : block_name not working

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.2

In [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field), it is said that we can redefine `block_name` for a better customisation but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is what I tried :

#### When declaring the collection

```
$builder
    ->add('medias', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => MediaType::class,
        'block_name' => 'media_proto'
    ));
```

#### On each collection's field

```
//MediaType.php
$builder
    ->add('detail', TextType::class, array(
        'translation_domain' => 'messages',
        'label' => 'person.medias.detail',
        'block_name' => 'media_proto'
    ))
    ->add('typeMedia', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'VSCrmBundle:TypeMedia',
        'choice_translation_domain' => true,
        'translation_domain' => 'messages',
        'label' => 'person.medias.type',
        'block_name' => 'media_proto'
    ))
```

#### Inside configureOptions of the collection

```
//MediaType.php
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'VS\CrmBundle\Entity\Media',
        'block_name' => 'media_proto'
    ));
}
```

The html generated is always the same

```
<input type="text" id="user_parent_person_medias_0_detail" name="user_parent[person][medias][0][detail]" required="required" class="" value="">
```

My purpose is to make those block names uniforms, so I can customize them globaly.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something because all of the Symfony stuff is pretty new to me.

Thanks

Comment: And if you will do that how will you process the data collections?

Comment: To show it or to customize it ?

Answer (score 0):

block_name is not part of the ineherited options of the texttype field. In order to rendered it you should add it with the

```
$builder
    ->add('detail', TextType::class, array(
        'translation_domain' => 'messages',
        'label' => 'person.medias.detail',
        'attr'=>array('block_name' => 'media_proto')
    ))
    ->add('typeMedia', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'VSCrmBundle:TypeMedia',
        'choice_translation_domain' => true,
        'translation_domain' => 'messages',
        'label' => 'person.medias.type',
        'attr'=>array('block_name' => 'media_proto')
    ))
```

Try it!

By the way, what you are trying to do with that specific link linked to the symfony docs need the part of the twig template and form _self code in the twig file in order to make it work that way.

**EDITED**

It seems this isn't working anymore. I remember this worked with sf2.

What you need to do is to identify the fields you need to override and then add the block you need to overwrite in twig. Let's imaging that your fields are: choice and text types and are taken from form_div_layout.html.twig:

```
{% form_theme name_of_your_form _self %}

{%- block form_widget_simple -%}
    {%- set type = type|default('text') -%}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %} block_name="media_proto"/> <!-- code you need -->
{%- endblock form_widget_simple -%}


{%- block choice_widget_collapsed -%}
    {%- if required and placeholder is none and not placeholder_in_choices and not multiple and (attr.size is not defined or attr.size <= 1) -%}
        {% set required = false %}
    {%- endif -%}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %} block_name="media_proto">
        {%- if placeholder is not none -%}
            <option value=""{% if required and value is empty %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ placeholder != '' ? (translation_domain is same as(false) ? placeholder : placeholder|trans({}, translation_domain)) }}</option>
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- if preferred_choices|length > 0 -%}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            {%- if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none -%}
                <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- set options = choices -%}
        {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
    </select>
{%- endblock choice_widget_collapsed -%}
```

I don't know if this would be the best solution but hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, this just add an attribute 'block_name' but it doesn't change the block_name.

I'm aware for the twig template and form _self, it is working but I can't customize de block_name

Comment: In Symfony 2.8. block_name must not be inside attr.